# Which Christian groups or denominations believe in modern-day Theophanies?

Tags: denomination-survey, spirituality, supernatural, theophany

Which denominations believe in modern-day *Theophanies*, i.e., that God still manifests/reveals Himself to individuals in extraordinary, supernatural ways **today**?

For the sake of having a common understanding of the term *Theophany*, I'd like to quote [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophany) (emphasis mine):

> **Theophany** (from Ancient Greek (ἡ) θεοφάνεια theophaneia,[1] meaning "appearance of a deity") **is a personal encounter with a deity, that is an event where the manifestation of a deity occurs in an observable way**.[2][3] **Specifically, it "refers to the temporal and spatial manifestation of God in some tangible form."**[4]
>
> Where the deity does not take tangible form (outward manifestation), the broader term used for inward manifestation is divine revelation or divine inspiration.[5] Where the spirit of god is manifest in a person the term used is divine incarnation, avatar or personification of the deity.[6]
>
> Traditionally the term "theophany" was used to refer to appearances of the gods in ancient Greek and in Near Eastern religions. While the Iliad is the earliest source for descriptions of theophanies in classical antiquity (which occur throughout Greek mythology), probably the earliest description appears in the Epic of Gilgamesh.[7]
>
> **In the specific usage for Christians and Jews, with respect to the Bible, theophany refers to an event where the Abrahamic God reveals his presence to a person**.

---

Similar/related questions:

- [Which Christian groups or denominations believe in modern-day Christophanies?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83590/50422)
- [Which denominations believe in modern angelic interventions?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86115/50422)
- [Which denominations believe in modern (ongoing) revelation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/66641/50422)

Comment: Which ones don't ?

Comment: @Lucian - are there any that **explicitly** say that they do?

Comment: Meaning what, exactly ?

Comment: @Lucian - what part do you not understand?

Comment: You might as well ask: *Which Christian denominations believe in Jesus ?*

Comment: @Lucian - so if someone comes by and tells you they had a Theophany the other day, you just accept it as easily as if someone comes by and tells you they believe in Jesus? (*"Hey bro, I had a Theophany yesterday, it was awesome."*)

Comment: Pick a few randomly chosen religious books, detailing the lives of Catholic or Orthodox saints or monastics, twentieth century onwards; or of a relatively recent (historically speaking) [Protestant pastor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Wurmbrand) or mystic.

Comment: @Lucian - it looks like you already have the beginning of what could potentially become your own answer to the question ;)

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I know Mormons believe in Theophanies. In fact their whole religion is solely based on Joseph Smith's account at age 14 in 1820 that God the Father and Jesus Christ appeared to him in a vision. I personally would put this in the category of today. The Jehovah Witnesses say Jesus appeared in 1914 but of course that was an invisible appearance and of course it cannot be proved for obvious reasons. I'm not sure about other religions but I do know people will say God or Jesus appeared to them in some form. That's my "two cents" worth but personally I don't buy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Charismatic movement.

The [Charismatic movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charismatic_movement) is a movement of churches and denominations that, in short, believe in the power of the Holy Spirit to move among modern-day Christians and perform miracles. One of the most common theophanic experiences among them is members of these churches being "blown down by the Holy Spirit"; sometimes, this is a weekly experience at the Sunday services of the churches. Some of them even go so far as to say that anyone who hasn't been "baptised in the Holy Spirit" in this fashion hasn't been truly Saved.

Whether these experiences are the result of genuine supernatural influence, the result of psychological manipulation by their pastors, or some combination of genuine experiences intermixed with those resulting from trickery is a matter of debate, but at the very least, it is a the doctrine of these churches is that these experiences are real encounters with one of the persons of God.